# Moving transformation matrices from shaders to the Javascript application

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, homogenous-transformation

I had to solve many tasks of an homework. I have to build a rotating cube with some buttons to apply changes and transformations. There is one task that asks to me "move the transformation matrices from the shaders to the js application" . I know how to build rotating , translating and scaling matrices in the shaders , but what does it mean to move them in the js application. I use to specify shaders in the html file.

Here is my code :

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<button id = "ButtonX">Rotate X</button>
<button id = "ButtonY">Rotate Y</button>
<button id = "ButtonZ">Rotate Z</button>
<button id = "ButtonT">Toggle Rotation</button>


<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;

varying vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 theta;

void main()
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    vec3 angles = radians( theta );
    vec3 c = cos( angles );
    vec3 s = sin( angles );

    // Remember: the matrices are column-major
    mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0,
            0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

    mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
            s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );


    mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, s.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            -s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition;
    gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;

}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Homework1.js"></script>

<button id="Direction">Change Direction</button>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="1024" height="1024">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;

var numVertices  = 36;

var numChecks = 8;

var program;

var c;

var flag = true;

var direction = true;

var pointsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];

var vertices = [
    vec4( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 1.0 ),
    vec4( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0 )
];

var vertexColors = [
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // black
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // magenta
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // white
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )   // cyan
];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;
var axis = xAxis;

var theta = [45.0, 45.0, 45.0];

var thetaLoc;

function quad(a, b, c, d) {
     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[b]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[a]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[c]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);

     pointsArray.push(vertices[d]);
     colorsArray.push(vertexColors[a]);
}

function colorCube()
{
    quad( 1, 0, 3, 2 );
    quad( 2, 3, 7, 6 );
    quad( 3, 0, 4, 7 );
    quad( 6, 5, 1, 2 );
    quad( 4, 5, 6, 7 );
    quad( 5, 4, 0, 1 );
}


window.onload = function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );

    colorCube();

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

    thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "theta");


 document.getElementById("ButtonX").onclick = function(){axis = xAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonY").onclick = function(){axis = yAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonZ").onclick = function(){axis = zAxis;};
 document.getElementById("ButtonT").onclick = function(){flag = !flag;};
 document.getElementById("Direction").onclick = function() { direction = !direction;};

    render();
}

var render = function() {
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Point 1 --> Change and Toggle Rotation
    if((direction)&&(!flag)) theta[axis] += -2.0;
    if((!direction)&&(!flag)) theta[axis] += +2.0;

    if(!direction) {theta[axis] += -2.0; }
    if(direction) {theta[axis] += 2.0 ; }
    //

    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices );
    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know how to build rotating , translating and scaling matrices in the shaders , but what does it mean to move them in the js application.

Fist you have to create a uniform variable with the type `mat4` in the shader program:

```
uniform mat4 rx;
```

In the js application you can use an array to setup the matrix. The matrix has to be constructed in column major order (or it has to be transposed when set to the uniform):

```
var theta_x_degree  = theta[0];
var theta_x_radians = theta_x_degree * Math.PI / 180;
var s_x = Math.sin(theta_x_radians );
var c_x = Math.cos(theta_x_radians );

var rx = [
    1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,
    0.0,  c_x,  s_x, 0.0,
    0.0, -s_x,  c_x, 0.0,
    0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0
];
```

After the shader program is linked (`gl.linkProgram`), the uniform location of the matrix uniform can be get:

```
var rx_loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rx");
```

Finally the uniform can be set, after the shader program has become the current program (`gl.useProgram`):

```
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rx_loc, false, rx); // false means "not transpose"
```

Comment: FYI: you don't need to convert them to `Float32Array` for `gl.uniform` and even using `Float32Array` to start is currently and always has been slower than using native JS arrays (though maybe someday that will change)

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks for the help , I applied the changes you suggest me , now I can display the cube after I moved the matrix but it does not rotate on the x axis.

Comment: @RickGrass What does it mean "it does not rotate on the x axis". Is that a new question? If you want to animate the object, then you have to to change and set the matrix continuously. You have to calculate and set the matrix in the `render` function.